# How to copy files from a folder( picking linkS from a sheet) to a new folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i need your help.
so i have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets: "file to copy" and "folder name"
"file to copy" has 5 column where in column C i have full link to files (are in different Drive folders), and in column E i have ID files. this list of files could contain also 4/500 files

I have a function that it works, but when save files it give me back html files (but there are pictures)

So i am at point that i can create the folder, but i cannot copy files

Is there someone that could help me to complete the function? i am a rookie here and i didn't find any right solution here.

thank you very much for your help

here the code until now

```
function copyImg() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      iniTime = Date.now()/1000,
      lr = ss.getSheetByName("file to copy").getLastRow(),//sheet where i have files to copy
      nameFolder =  ss.getRange("folder name!$A$2").getValue() + " " + ss.getRange("folder name!$B$2").getDisplayValue();//name of the destination folder

  var sourceFileId = ss.getRange("e1:e").getValues();//range where i have ID files
  var folders =  DriveApp.getFoldersByName(nameFolder)
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(nameFolder);
  }
    }
//here i have problems to get files and push into the new folder
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so i have a sheet that contain ID of files that i need to copy to a new folder created with a function. I didn't understand how get values and copy there. I added comment and i hope there will be enough for understand the problem. here the link to file [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FkhKAvWL-zmhU_rSwRVn4pTo9umi7bwY8ATRSCgsZs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I have a function that it works, but when save files it give me back html files (but there are pictures)` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?